# Creating a Hire Date for AD users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a random Date Generator, but I am now trying to add this date to the desctiption of each user on the domain. As of now the only other thing in the Description is their age which is just a number. So I want it to be: Description: age, date hired

When I run this code it asks for a filter I then put in a user name and I get an error with Get-ADUser -Prop description.

Is this going through all users? or Am I using the wrong filter?

syntax error:
Get-ADUser -Prop Description

```
$StartDate = Get-Date -Date 2015-01-01
$EndDate = Get-Date -Date 2022-11-11

$RangeInDays = 0..(($EndDate - $StartDate).Days)
$DaysToAdd = Get-Random -InputObjects $RangeInDays
$RandDate = $Startdate.AddDays($DaysToAdd)

Get-ADUser -Prop Description | ForEach {
    $desc = $._description + $RandDate Set-ADUser $_.sAMAccountName -Description $desc
}
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: I am getting an error with my Get-ADUser -Prop Description I do not think It is going through each user.

Comment: What is the error, include in your post please

Comment: The `Set-ADUser...` should be on its own line, and don't you want to format the DateTime object in `$RandDate` ?

Comment: As for your remark about the Filter, you're not using any in your code.. You could add `-Filter *` to the Get-ADUser cmdlet, but please tell us why you would want to put a random date in a users description

Comment: I am simulating a hire date for each user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comments,

- your code does not include a `-Filter` on the Get-ADUser cmdlet
- `$._description` is wrong syntax and should be `$_.Description`
- `Get-Random -InputObjects $RangeInDays` is wrong syntax and should be
  `Get-Random -InputObject $RangeInDays`
- if you want the description to be 'age, randomdate' you need to format it that way
- if you want a different random date on each user, you need to recreate that random date inside the loop
- Set-ADUser should be on its own line
- your example dates do not show whether you want the date as 'yyyy-MM-dd' or 'yyyy-dd-MM'

Try

```
$StartDate   = Get-Date -Date '2015/01/01'  # format yyyy/MM/dd
$EndDate     = Get-Date -Date '2022/11/11'  # format yyyy/MM/dd
$RangeInDays = 0..(($EndDate - $StartDate).Days - 1)

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Description | ForEach-Object {
    $DaysToAdd = Get-Random -InputObject $RangeInDays
    $RandDate = $Startdate.AddDays($DaysToAdd)
    $desc = '{0}, {1}' -f $_.Description, $RandDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    $_ | Set-ADUser -Description $desc
}
```

Comment: This is the full error I get:                                                 Cannot convert argument "value", with value: "4/25/2016 12:00:00 AM", for "AddDays"
to type "System.Double": "Cannot convert value "4/25/2016 12:00:00 AM" to type
"System.Double". Error: "Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Double'.""
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\hireDate.ps1:10 char:5
+  $RandDate = $StartDate.AddDays($DaysToAdd)
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo       : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Comment: @Tiberious That means you do not have proper DateTime objects earlier up.

Comment: @Tiberious I only concentrated on the loop itself, but your error shows something above that loop goes wrong, but I cannot see what you did there, so I have now edited my answer to show the ful code.